# Lazy loading Giscus on user interaction

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

I am integrating Giscus into my website for comments. I want to load the Giscus script dynamically after either a mouse movement or scrolling event on the page.

I would like to modify this script so that the Giscus script loads when the user moves the mouse or scrolls the page. I have tried adding event listeners for both mouse movement and scrolling, but I'm not getting the desired result.

Here's my attempt:

```html
<!-- Modified Giscus Script with Event Listeners -->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
      const themeToggle = document.querySelector('.darkmode-toggle input');
      const light = 'light';
      const dark = 'dark';
      let isDark = localStorage.theme === dark || (!('theme' in localStorage) && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches);
      let theme = isDark ? dark : light;
  
      const s = document.createElement('script');
      s.type = 'text/javascript';
      const dataset = {
          repo: '{{ .repo }}',
          repoId: '{{ .repoId }}',
          category: '{{ .category }}',
          categoryId: '{{ .categoryId }}',
          mapping: '{{ .mapping }}',
          reactionsEnabled: '{{ .reactionsEnabled }}',
          emitMetadata: '{{ .emitMetadata }}',
          theme: theme,
          lang: '{{ .lang }}',
      };
      s.src = 'https://giscus.app/client.js';
      s.crossorigin = 'anonymous';
      s.async = true;
      Object.entries(dataset).forEach(function(a) {
          return s.dataset[a[0]] = a[1];
      });
  
      const curScriptElement = document.currentScript;
      curScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(s, curScriptElement);
  
      function sendMessage(message) {
        const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe.giscus-frame');
        // console.log(iframe);
        if (!iframe) return;
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage({ giscus: message }, 'https://giscus.app');
      }
  
      function loadGiscusScript() {
        if (!s.parentElement) {
          curScriptElement.parentNode.insertBefore(s, curScriptElement);
        }
      }
  
      document.addEventListener('mouse-move', loadGiscusScript);
      window.addEventListener('scroll-window', loadGiscusScript);
  
      themeToggle.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
          theme = dark;
        } else {
          theme = light;
        }
        sendMessage({
          setConfig: {
            theme: theme,
          }
        });
      });
    })();
  </script>
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as expected. The Giscus script doesn't load after mouse movement or scrolling.

Can someone please help me understand what I might be doing wrong, and suggest a solution to dynamically load the Giscus script after mouse movement or scrolling events?

Any insights or alternative approaches would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You've got quite a lot of code here and some of it is not relevant to lazy loading this tool. Could you trim this down to only the relevant code please?

Comment: Thank you, now I have only added the code attempt, this is the attempt to load giscus on mousemove or scroll event, still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, there are no such events as you have demonstrated. Instead the event is [`mousemove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) and [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

But, this is not an ideal approach. As coded, you're going to continually trigger the event listener. You can do this by adding the [`once`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#once) option like this: `listener.addEventListener(eventName, handler, { once: true })`.

But what you should be looking at is an [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), which will trigger when an element is in view